# KDevelop script gives error on `view.selection()`

Tags: javascript, ide, code-snippets, kde-plasma, kdevelop

I am trying to write the simplest ever snippet for Kdevelop (5.1).
It should simply take my selected text and embrace it with `#if 0 ... #endif`.

```
#if 0
my current selection
#endif
```

Snippet code is:

```
#if 0 
${view.selection()}
#endif
```

And all I receive back is the error:

```
#if 0 
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Range
#endif
```

All I know is that this Kate / Kdevelop snippets use Javascript, so I think this simple `view.selection()` oughta work, but it doesn't.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want?
How to fix this `Range` error?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I added a function `selection_or_nothing()` to the functions tab, a `require ("range.js")` before it and changed my snippet to call it.

```
require ("range.js");
function selection_or_nothing() 
{
    if ( view.hasSelection() )
        return view.selection();
    return "";
}
```

Snippet:

```
#if 0
${selection_or_nothing()}
#endif  // ${comment}
```

This is what I have now:

```
#if 0
Range(Cursor(200,0), Cursor(201,0))
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works here:

```
#if 0
${selection()}
#endif
```

I think you need to use view.selectedText() instead of view.selection(), or this pre-defined function.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sven Brauch. I found out about `view.selectedText()` a few hours earlier. Unfortunately `${selection()}` doesn' t work for me. No problem. `view.selectedText()` works great.